# Deserialize JSON to Dictionary

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I want to deserialize a Json to the following class

```
public class Config
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public SSOType Type { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<String, String> Configuration { get; set; }
}
```

Hence, two properties would be deserialized "as usual", and the rest would be pushed into the dictionary.

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Config>(filetext);
```

This pushs datas to properties Name and Type, but the dictionary stays empty ...

I guess the json shall look like

```
{
    "name":"something",
    "type":"something",
    "configuration":{
        "thing1":"value",
        "thing2":"value",
        "thing3":"value"
            }
}
```

but I'd like the json to be like

```
{
    "name":"something",
    "type":"something",
    "thing1":"value",
    "thing2":"value",
    "thing3":"value"
}
```

How to tweak the deserialization so it works ?

Comment: Edited to add more things

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
public class Config : Dictionary<string, string>
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public SSOType Type { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Properties will be ignored, iirc.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Looks like this is a way to make those properties be included - http://stackoverflow.com/a/14894945/906690

Answer (score 0):

Your options:

1. `JsonExtensionDataAttribute` on a dictionary which will get all data for which properties are not found, and `OnDesrialized` callback to convert the dictionary to the format you need:

   ```
   public class Config
   {
       public String Name { get; set; }

       [JsonIgnore]
       public Dictionary<string, string> Configuation { get; set; }

       [JsonExtensionData]
       private Dictionary<string, JToken> _configuration;

       [OnDeserialized]
       private void Deserialized (StreamingContext context)
       {
           Configuation = _configuration.ToDictionary(i => i.Key, i => (string)i.Value);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Custom `JsonConverter` which will read JSON DOM and convert it to your class. You can find many examples on StackOverflow.