# JSON data is not bound with Dictionary property during deserialization

Tags: c#, json, elasticsearch, json.net, nest

I am using Nest for querying data that binds with a corresponding property using Newtonsoft.Json.

Below is a property of a class that is not being populated with JSON data.

```
[JsonExtensionData]
IDictionary<long, ICollection<Tuple<string, byte[ ]>>> ImageMap { get; set; }
```

However, others are correctly bound.
I am using Newtonsoft.Json 7.0.1.

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to include the JSON you are trying to deserialize.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using the `[JsonExtensionData]` attribute inappropriately.  `[JsonExtensionData]` is intended to be used to capture extra data from the JSON for which you did not explicitly define properties in your class.  To use it properly, the dictionary in your class must be declared as a `Dictionary<string, object>` or `Dictionary<string, JToken>`.  (See [How to serialize a Dictionary as part of its parent object using Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14893614/10263) for a simple example.)

However, in your case, you have a very specific `ImageMap` property in your class which is intended to capture the data from the corresponding `imageMap` property in the JSON.  This doesn't fit the use case for extension data at all.  Remove the `[JsonExtensionData]` attribute and replace it with `[JsonProperty("imageMap")]`; then it should deserialize correctly.

```
[JsonProperty("imageMap")]
public IDictionary<long, ICollection<Tuple<string, byte[]>>> ImageMap { get; set; }
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/05J7Wo

Comment: Thank for explaining the right use of JsonExtentionData.