# C# How to I deserialize a dynamic json with json.net

Tags: c#, json.net

I have to deserialize a json with json.net

Json data like:

[image]

The green blocks' property name(key) was fixed,

but the others were dynamic and the quantity of them not fixed.

How to i declare my class to deserialize the data

use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString)

or other best solution?

Comment: Maybe a custom `ContractResolver` might help?

Comment: You'll need to serialize it into a `Dictionary` if you don't know the keys.

Comment: Sounds like your objects have a fixed schema + additional variable properties.  If so, see [How to serialize a Dictionary as part of its parent object using Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14893614) and also [Deserialize json with known and unknown fields](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15253875).