# Newtonsoft Deserialize to Object Store Underlying JSON as property

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am using Newtonsoft to deserialize JSON from a REST call to a C# object. The object is a list of Person.  The Person has a lot of properties but right now I am only storing some of them.  I want to have a string property on the Person that contains the JSON that makes up the whole person.  Is there a way to do this?  I am writing it back to a SQL database for now and I don't need the values but want to have it for future use if needed.

Object class

```
public class Worker
{
    public string associateOID { get; set; }
    public WorkerID workerID { get; set; }
    public Person person { get; set; }
    public WorkerDates workerDates { get; set; }
    public WorkerStatus workerStatus { get; set; }
    public List<WorkAssignment> workAssignments { get; set; }
    public CustomFieldGroup customFieldGroup { get; set; }
    public BusinessCommunication businessCommunication { get; set; }
    public string JSON { get; set; }
}

public class Meta
{
    public int totalNumber { get; set; }
}

public class WorkerResult
{
    public List<Worker> workers { get; set; }
    public Meta meta { get; set; }
}
```

My existing call to deserialize:

```
WorkerResult result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WorkerResult>(json);
```

Comment: Sure it is possible. What is the issue you are having? Do you have any code written?

Comment: I updated my original to include the object classes and my code for the Deserialize.  Not really sure where to go from there.  Didn't see any attributes to do it.

Comment: With NewtonSoft, this is straight forward. Just set the `JSON` property of your class to the `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`.

Comment: Within my Worker class I am only grabbing some of the properties from the JSON, but want to store all JSON with properties for the database.

Comment: It's doable with a custom `JsonConverter`, but would [`[JsonExtensionData]`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonExtensionDataAttribute.htm) suit your needs better?  See [How to serialize a Dictionary as part of its parent object using Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23786127/3744182) and [Deserialize json with known and unknown fields](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21763919/3744182).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add JsonIgnore attribute to your JSON property like this:

```
[JsonIgnore()]
public string JSON { get; set; }
```

You can use do this after you have deserialized the object

```
JObject workerResult = JObject.Parse(json);

// this should contain a list of all the workers
IList<JToken> workers = workerResult["workers"].Children().ToList();
```

After that, iterate all the workers in the `result` object you obtained earlier and set the `JSON` property to the equivalent worker object

```
for (int i = 0; i < result.workers.Count; i++)
    result.workers[i].JSON = workers[i].ToString();
```

Comment: The JSON is in an object 2 levels down that is in a list.

Comment: @JasonWebber I have updated my answer to match your objects

Answer (score 4):

I think you mean that you want to store all attributes from the JSON into your c#  object - so that you can access them later if you need to.

To do this, you use the `[JsonExtensionData]` annotation.

```
public class Worker
{
    public string associateOID { get; set; }
    // Any other attributes that you want to use as .NET types go here

    // all attributes that don't have a property will be put into this dictionary
    // either as primitive types, or as objects of type Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject
    // supports nested objects of any Json structure, and will serialize correctly.
    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string,object> ExtraAttributes {get;set;}
}
```

You can see a full example at https://dotnetfiddle.net/N5SuCY.

To store these properties in a database, you can combine this with a calculated string property:

```
[JsonIgnore]
public string SerializedExtraAttributes => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ExtraAttributes);
```