# C# Optimal object or class structure for deserialized json

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a json structured like that:

```
{
  "eventType1": {
    "unitName": "nameValue",
    "comment": "initial comment"
  },
  "eventType2": {
    "comment": "initial message"
  },
}
```

When I deserialize it the appropriate type seems to be something like `Dictionary<string, <Dictionary<string,string>>>` and method would look like that:

```
public static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> defaultFieldDataByEvent =
        JsonConvert
        .DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>(defaultFieldDataByEventSerialized);
```

which looks, well, ugly. But that's exactly how I need it to extract the data - `defaultFieldDataByEvent[eventType][field]`.

Can I encapsulate the type into something somehow or is there a different approach to such cases?

Comment: Is there a fixed set of possible properties for the `"eventTypeX"` objects?  If so, I would define an `EventData` class and deserialize to `Dictionary<string, EventData>`

Comment: @dbc, not exactly, that's why a dictionary, not a defined custom class. I would define an `EventData` class otherwise. I'd like to do it here as well, but I don't know how to populate the encapsulated dictionary when deserializing

Comment: If `EventData` would need to consist of fixed and variable properties, `[JsonExtensionData]` might fit your needs.  See [How to serialize a Dictionary as part of its parent object using Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14893614/3744182).

Comment: You may try to add a type alias with `using` directive to make code shorter, but this won't be convenient if logic is spread across multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

I see multiple possible options here. Hope any of these helps.

- You may try to add a type alias with [using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive) directive to make code shorter, but this won't be convenient, if logic is spread across multiple files, because you will be forced to duplicate this alias.
- You may try to use [`JObject.Parse`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ParseJsonObject.htm) for deserialization, staying on lower level. But as far as your json structure is pretty various, this approach may work well.
- You may try to deserialize your data into [`ExpandoObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?view=netframework-4.7.2). It's rather similar to `JObject`, except you will get pretty nice dynamic code (dynamic is not a problem here since compiler won't help you with `Dictionary` either), but it, obviously will be less performant. You could lose your custom types information, since everything in your graph will become an `ExpandoObject`, but seems like that's not an issue for your case. [Example](http://www.tomdupont.net/2014/02/deserialize-to-expandoobject-with.html) may be found here.
- You may try to use `[JsonExtensionData]` as @dbc suggested. See [How to serialize a Dictionary as part of its parent object using Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893614/how-to-serialize-a-dictionary-as-part-of-its-parent-object-using-json-net).