# Serialize single KeyValuePair<> to JSON as part of a parent object

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I have a DTO class like this:

```cs
public class MyDto
{
    public KeyValuePair<string, string> Identifier { get; set; }

    public double Value1 { get; set; }

    public string Value2 { get; set; }
}
```

And two instances could look like this:

```cs
var results = new List<MyDto> 
{
    new MyDto
    {
        Identifier = new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Car", "Ford"),
        Value1 = 13,
        Value2 = "A"
    },
    new MyDto 
    {
        Identifier = new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Train", "Bombardier"),
        Value1 = 14,
        Value2 = "B"
    },
};
```

When serializing the results within ASP.NET Web API (which uses Json.NET), the output looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "Identifier": {
      "Key": "Car",
      "Value": "Ford"
    },
    "Value1": 13,
    "Value2": "A"
  },
  {
    "Identifier": {
      "Key": "Train",
      "Value": "Bombardier"
    },
    "Value1": 14,
    "Value2": "B"
  }
]
```

But I'd like to have it that way:

```
[
  {
    "Car": "Ford",
    "Value1": 13,
    "Value2": "A"
  },
  {
    "Train": "Bombardier",
    "Value1": 14,
    "Value2": "B"
  }
]
```

How can I achieve this? Do I have to write a custom `JsonConverter` and do everything by hand? Since the DTO class is located in a separate assembly not having access to Json.NET, the usage of specific Json.NET attributes is not possible.

I'm not bound to using `KeyValuePair<string, string>`. I only need a data structure that allows me to have a flexible attribute name.

Comment: The `System.Text.Json` implementation of JSON in .NET Core 3+ currently has a lot of limitations, one being its inability to properly serialize `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` properties. Currently it's planned to be resolved in .NET 5.0 (to be released in November 2020) The ongoing issue is being tracked here: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30524

Comment: @silkfire _When serializing these two instances using Json.NET_

Comment: I'm using .NET Framework, not .NET Core

Comment: _Do I have to write a custom JsonConverter_ - they really aren't that complicated to do. But the easy way is to just use a single entry dictionary like Marc suggests in his answer.

Comment: Presumably you are actually serializing a `List<MyDto>` even though the outer brackets aren't shown, correct?  If so, just switch to a `List<Dictionary<string, string>>` and add a single entry to each dictionary.  `MyDto` is no longer necessary.  That's what Marc is suggesting.

Comment: @dbc You're right, I'm working with an `IEnumerable<MyDto>`. But `MyDto` contains more than the one shown property, so I need this type.

Comment: Are you saying that you need a fixed set of properties + exactly one variably named property in each object?  If so that completely changes your requirement.  Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: @dbc I hope it's clearer now

Comment: In that case make `Identifier` be a `Dictionary<string, object>` and add `[JsonExtensionData]` as shown in [How to serialize a Dictionary as part of its parent object using Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23786127/3744182).  in fact I think this is now a duplicate.

Comment: I don't have access to the Json.NET library from the assembly where `MyDto` is located, so I cannot annotate the `Identifier` with `JsonExtensionData`

Comment: You can't add Json.NET attributes but can you add your own custom attributes?

Answer (score 2):

Edit: this answer applies to the question *as originally asked*; it has subsequently been edited, and may now be less useful

---

You may need to use a dictionary that has a single element, i.e. `Dictionary<string,string>`, which *does* serialize in the way you want; for example:

```cs
var obj = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Car", "Ford" } };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
System.Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Comment: I've tried your code, but it serializes to `"Identifier": { "Car": "Ford" }`, but not `{ "Car": "Ford" }`

Comment: That's cause `Identifier` is the name of your property. As per the *default* behaviour, this is correct.

Comment: That may be true, but it's not what I need.

Comment: Then you'd need a custom converter as you suggested yourself :)

Comment: @mu88 you'll notice I didn't serialize an object *with* an identifier that was a dictionary; I serialized *just the dictionary*

Comment: This correctly answers the question as originally written, but the question has been updated to add requirements for fixed & variable property names in the same object.

Comment: @dbc thanks for the heads-up; I've edited to clarify this, but ultimately: I can only answer the question as written at the time I post

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a `KeyValuePair<>`, you can easily serialize a dictionary as part of a parent object by applying [`[JsonExtensionData]`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonExtensionDataAttribute.htm) like so:

```
public class MyDto
{
    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, object> Identifier { get; set; }
```

However, you have stated that *the usage of specific Json.NET attributes is not possible.*  But since you can generally modify your DTO you could mark it with a **custom extension data attribute** and then handle that attribute in either a [custom generic `JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) or a [custom contract resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm#CustomIContractResolverExamples).

**Firstly**, for an example of using a custom extension data attribute with a custom `JsonConverter`, see `JsonTypedExtensionData` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40094403/3744182) to *[How to deserialize a child object with dynamic (numeric) key names?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40088941/3744182)*

**Secondly**, if you prefer not to use a converter, to handle a custom extension data attribute with a custom contract resolver, first define the following contract resolver:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class MyJsonExtensionDataAttribute : Attribute
{
}

public class MyContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonObjectContract CreateObjectContract(Type objectType)
    {
        var contract = base.CreateObjectContract(objectType);
        if (contract.ExtensionDataGetter == null && contract.ExtensionDataSetter == null)
        {
            var dictionaryProperty = contract.Properties
                .Where(p => typeof(IDictionary<string, object>).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType) && p.Readable && p.Writable)
                .Where(p => p.AttributeProvider.GetAttributes(typeof(MyJsonExtensionDataAttribute), false).Any())
                .SingleOrDefault();
            if (dictionaryProperty != null)
            {
                dictionaryProperty.Ignored = true;
                contract.ExtensionDataGetter = o => 
                    ((IDictionary<string, object>)dictionaryProperty.ValueProvider.GetValue(o)).Select(p => new KeyValuePair<object, object>(p.Key, p.Value));
                contract.ExtensionDataSetter = (o, key, value) =>
                    {
                        var dictionary = (IDictionary<string, object>)dictionaryProperty.ValueProvider.GetValue(o);
                        if (dictionary == null)
                        {
                            dictionary = (IDictionary<string, object>)this.ResolveContract(dictionaryProperty.PropertyType).DefaultCreator();
                            dictionaryProperty.ValueProvider.SetValue(o, dictionary);
                        }
                        dictionary.Add(key, value);
                    };
                }
                contract.ExtensionDataValueType = typeof(object);
                // TODO set contract.ExtensionDataNameResolver
        }
        return contract;
    }
}
```

Then modify your DTO as follows:

```
public class MyDto
{
    [MyJsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, object> Identifier { get; set; }

    public double Value1 { get; set; }

    public string Value2 { get; set; }
}
```

And serialize as follows, caching a static instance of your resolver for performance:

```
static IContractResolver resolver = new MyContractResolver();

// And later

    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ContractResolver = resolver,
    };

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results, Formatting.Indented, settings);
```

Notes:

- The `MyJsonExtensionData` property's type must be assignable to type `IDictionary<string, object>` and have a public, parameterless constructor.
- Naming strategies for extension data property names are not implemented.
- Json.NET serializes extension data attributes at the end of each object whereas your question shows the custom attributes at the beginning.  Since a JSON object is defined to be an *unordered set of name/value pairs* by the [standard](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) I think this should not matter.  But if you require the custom properties at the beginning of your object, you may need to use a custom converter rather than a custom contract resolver.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/t0kxKv).

Answer (score 1):

Since your `MyDto` class is in a separate assembly for which you have limitations in the kinds of changes you can make, then yes, I think your best bet is to create a custom converter for the class.  Something like this should work:

```
public class MyDtoConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(MyDto);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        MyDto dto = (MyDto)value;
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        writer.WritePropertyName(dto.Identifier.Key);
        writer.WriteValue(dto.Identifier.Value);
        var contract = (JsonObjectContract)serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(typeof(MyDto));
        foreach (JsonProperty prop in contract.Properties.Where(p => p.PropertyName != nameof(MyDto.Identifier)))
        {
            writer.WritePropertyName(prop.PropertyName);
            writer.WriteValue(prop.ValueProvider.GetValue(dto));
        }
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }

    public override bool CanRead => false;

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

To use it you will need to add the converter to your Web API configuration:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new MyDtoConverter());
```

Here is a working demo of the converter in a console app: https://dotnetfiddle.net/DksgMZ