# How to obtain a list of dynamic object keys/values from NewtonSoft Deserialised into Dynamic var

Tags: c#, json

I have a C# class that receives a JSON string, and deserialises it into a dynamic.

```
json = @"{  
    "Id": "97dc4a96-43cf-48bd-9358-8f33e910594e",  
    "RepId": 90037,  
    "Something": true, 
    "SomethingElse": "abcdefg",
    "Thing_1_of_MaybeDozens": 55
}";

dynamic jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
```

I can't deserialse into a class because while each JSON string will always have two known data elements (`Id`, and `RepId`), the rest of the string may have many elements that I do not know ahead of time their names, or how many of them there are.

I can always ask for `jsonData.Id`, or `jsonData.RepId`, but I do not know how many other elements there may be, nor how to refer to them.

I need something similar to JavaScript's `Object.Keys(myObject)`.

Anyone knows how to do similar in C# with a Newtonsoft Deserialised JSON string?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deserialize JSON into C# dynamic object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object)

Comment: Did you try to cast to `ExpandObject`? If you can, you can enumerate keys like a regular dictionay.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to serialize a Dictionary as part of its parent object using Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893614/how-to-serialize-a-dictionary-as-part-of-its-parent-object-using-json-net)

Comment: You're looking for `[JsonExtensionData]` on a `Dictionary<string, object>` property

Comment: Hi Mark, and thanks for the suggestion.  Yes, that would have helped.  While entering my post's title, if SO had suggested that one I probably would have taken it.  Good to know, now, though.  SO doesn't always recommend similar questions that actually match.  So, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Reflection:

```
public Dictionary<string, object> DynamicToDictionary(dynamic obj)
{
     var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
     foreach (PropertyDescriptor pd in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(obj))
     {
        object obj2 = pd.GetValue(obj);
        dict.Add(pd.Name, obj2);
     }
     return dict;
}
```

Now you may use the dictionary's `TryGetValue()`, and `ContainsKey()`.

Comment: Perfect!  That's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @KirbyL.Wallace glad if I could help

Comment: This is working just great, except when one of the properties is an empty array (sorry, I can't format it properly in a comment:  
{
  "Id": "97dc4a96-43cf-48bd-9358-8f33e910594e",
  "RepId": 90037,
  "Weight": 215,
  "ScaleReadings": [],
  "Email": "pacer@yahoo.com"
 }  

ScaleReadings throws error when the property is an empty array: 'The name 'Value' is bound to a method and cannot be used like a property.' @Ashkan Mobayen Khiabani

Comment: @KirbyL.Wallace there are many possible solutions to this, but the easiest ones I think would be 1. `if(pd.IsArray()) { //do something }` or 2. just remove the empty arrays from json string : `[\w"]+\s*:\s*\[\]\s*,*` , here is the example [https://regex101.com/r/1sNJ1T/1](https://regex101.com/r/1sNJ1T/1)

Comment: pd.IsArray() will be great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try to use  Newtonsoft.Json extensions

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);
```

list of keys

```
List<string> additionalKeys=data.AdditionalData.Select(ad => ad.Key).ToList();
```

output

```
["Something","SomethingElse","Thing_1_of_MaybeDozens"]
```

how to use

```
var id = data.Id;  //97dc4a96-43cf-48bd-9358-8f33e910594e

var somethingElse = data.AdditionalData["SomethingElse"]; // abcdefg
```

class

```
public class Data
{
    // normal deserialization
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public long RepId { get; set; }

    //additional data
    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, object> AdditionalData {get;set;}
}
```