# How to Convert Dictionary (with Array as Value) to List in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, dictionary

I need to convert a `dictionary` into a `list` so that I can bind it to a grid.

My `dictionary` has `string` as a **key**, and an `array` of `doubles` as a **value**.

I can convert the `dictionary` to a `list` by using the `ToList<>` function on the `dictionary`, but when I bind it to the grid, the `array` is displayed as an object in the grid column.

How can I add the values in the `array` of `doubles` to the `list`? Is there a way for me to extract the `array` values into the list at the same time as I'm converting the `dictionary` to a `list`?

This is what I'm currently doing:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, double[]>> dataList = 
                    dataDictionary.ToList<KeyValuePair<string, double[]>>();
```

I need to preserve the `string` and both `double` values in the `array` (the array of doubles is of size two) to display in the grid.

I have looked at this, but couldn't implement it for what I need:
[Convert dictionary to List<KeyValuePair>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557220/convert-dictionary-to-listkeyvaluepair)

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Marwan

PS - I have also thought about converting the `dictionary` to a `datatable` so that I can bind it to the grid, but I'm not sure if that's doable.

Comment: It's not quite clear for me what you want to achieve. Your question reads as if you want the keys and values be mixed together in one list. Binding it to a grid would result in one column with keys and values in it. That doesn't seem to make too much sense. Maybe you can elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - Hi Daniel. I'm trying to have each key (string) and value (double[0] and double[1]) to display in its own row but in separate columns. I hope that helps clarify it a bit :-)

In the code that I have above, I can to convert a `dictionary` to a `list`. When I bind the `list` to the grid, it shows the **key** (string) in a column, and the **value** (double array of size two) is in another column, but it is displayed as an array object (values are not visible).

I need the values from the array to be displayed in their own columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Dictionary To List**

```
    Dictionary<string, double[]> dict = new Dictionary<string, double[]>();
    dict.Add("1", new double[] { 1.10, 1.20 });
    dict.Add("2", new double[] { 2.10, 2.20 });
    dict.Add("3", new double[] { 3.10, 3.20 });
    dict.Add("4", new double[] { 4.10, 4.20 });
    dict.Add("5", new double[] { 5.10, 5.20 });

     var lstRecord = dict.Select(i => new { Key = i.Key, Val1 = i.Value[0], Val2 = i.Value[1] }).ToList();
     dataGridView1.DataSource = lstRecord;
```

**Dictionary To Datatable**

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Dictionary<string, double[]> dict = new Dictionary<string, double[]>();
            dict.Add("1", new double[] { 1.10, 1.20 });
            dict.Add("2", new double[] { 2.10, 2.20 });
            dict.Add("3", new double[] { 3.10, 3.20 });
            dict.Add("4", new double[] { 4.10, 4.20 });
            dict.Add("5", new double[] { 5.10, 5.20 });

            dataGridView1.DataSource = Dictionary2Table(dict);
        }

        public DataTable Dictionary2Table(Dictionary<string, double[]> dict)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("key", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Value1", typeof(double));
            dt.Columns.Add("Value2", typeof(double));
            dict
                .Select(i => new { Key = i.Key, Val1 = i.Value[0], Val2 = i.Value[1] })
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(i=>dt.Rows.Add(i.Key,i.Val1,i.Val2));
            return dt;
        }
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

```
IList<double> list = dictionary.SelectMany(item => item.Value).ToList();
```

> I need to preserve the string and both double values in the array (the
>   array of doubles is of size two) to display in the grid.

You should implement additional logic that will iterate thru `array` on the view. Also you can create `Tuple<string,double,double>` and bind 2 `double` values manually.

```
            Func<double[], int, double?> safeGet = (array, index) => array.Length - 1 >= index ? (double?)array[index] : null;
            var list = dataList.Select(item => Tuple.Create(item.Key, safeGet(item.Value, 0), safeGet(item.Value, 1))).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    Dictionary<string, double[]> dict = new Dictionary<string, double[]>()
    {
        {"a",new double[]{1,2}},
        {"b",new double[]{3,4}}
    };
        List<Tuple<string, double, double>> list = dict.Select(kvp => Tuple.Create(kvp.Key, kvp.Value[0], kvp.Value[1])).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this

```
public class HelperClass
{
    private readonly KeyValuePair<string, double[]> Item;

    [Bindable]
    public string Key { get { return Item.Key; } }

    [Bindable]
    public double Value1 {get { return Item.Value[0]; } }

    [Bindable]
    public double Value2 {get { return Item.Value[1]; } }

    public HelperClass(KeyValuePair<string, double[]> item)
    {
        this.Item = item;
    }
}

public List<HelperClass> Convert(Dictionary<string, double[]> items)
{
    var result = new List<HelperClass>(items.Count);
    foreach(var item in items)
        result.Add(new HelperClass(item));
    return result;
}
```

Now you can bind your Grid to the `List<HelperClass>`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Tuple for this:

```
var result = dataDictionary.Select(x => Tuple.Create(x.Key, x.Value[0], x.Value[1]))
                           .ToList();
```